# How can I remove the portion between the ">" and the word "Bacteria" for each occurrence in a file?

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I want to remove the portion between the `>` and the word `Bacteria` for each occurrence in a file.

- Here is an example of the input:

  ```
  >AADV02000003.105686.107093 Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
  ```
- The result should look like this:

  ```
  >Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
  ```

This is a FASTA file (a common file format in bioniformatics), so the `>` will always be the first non-whitespace character on the line, and there will be only *one* such character on the line.

I was thinking about using `sed` but I am not sure how to set up the command. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is an improperly worded post. Just look at the title and none of the solutions match it. Why mention Bacteria wHen it has no role to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a fasta file, with multiple header and sequence lines, where the headers start with a `>` and the `>` can only occur as the first non-whitespace character of a line, you can do:

```
sed 's/^ *>[^ ]* />/' file.fa
```

That will look for lines that start with 0 or more spaces and then a `>` and, replace everything from the beginning of the line, through the `>` and until the first space with `>`, effectively removing everything before the first space.

To edit the original file instead of printing it to standard output, use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^ *>[^ ]* />/' file.fa
```

That will create a file named `file.fa.bak` which will be a copy of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z][^ ]* //' input_file
>Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
```

Comment: this worked! Thank you. Do you know how to add a ; at the end of each line that begins with ">". ?

Comment: @CallahanMcGoverm note that this might break your file if you have any spaces in any of the sequence lines. For example, if you have a trailing space in one of your lines, this would completely remove it. Try with `echo 'ACTG ' | sed 's/[A-Z][^ ]* //'`. This is why I asked you to clarify if this is indeed a fasta file or something else. If it's just a list of headers, you should be fine.

Comment: @CallahanMcGoverm Can you elaborate? Please ask a new question with this requirement and provide an example of the output needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ \> <(.+?)> Bacteria\; //;'
```

Briefly, Raku's `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags are used, in conjunction with the familiar `s///` substitution operator. The left half of the operator searches for 4 regex atoms, the zero-width `^` start-of string atom, a backslash escaped `\>`, a non-greedy `.+?` any-character one-or-more times, followed by the word `Bacteria\;`.

The non-greedy `.+?` atom is wrapped in `<(`…`)>`, which are Raku's *capture markers*. All four atoms (elements) are searched for, but only the `<(.+?)>` is captured for replacement in the right half of the substitution operator.

Finally, the right half of the substitution operator contains no characters, which tells Raku to take the capture and delete it ('substitute-with-nothing').

Sample Input:

```
>AADV02000003.105686.107093 Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
```

Sample Output:

```
>Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org/

Answer (score -1):

Gnu sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/>\S+/>/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use *grep* instead.  If you only want bacteria lines,

`grep -o 'Bact.*$' file.fa`

If the desired content may be anything following the first space, you could use (though it would include leading space):

`grep -o ' .*$' file.fa`

If you only want lines that begin with '>', and matching any trailing content, it would take two steps:

`grep '^>.*$' file.fa | grep -o ' .*$'`

Answer (score -1):

command:

```
sed "s/^>.* />/g" filename
```

output

```
>Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
```

command

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,1)$2}' filename
```

output

```
>Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;Cyanobacteriia;Cyanobacteriales;
```